# python - define huge matrices return memoryerror on windows

Tags: python, numpy

I'm defining big, multidimensional matrices using numpy. I run my code on my 64-bit ubuntu 13.10 system with 4GB RAM without any problems but when I try to run it on a 64-bit windows 7 system with 4GB RAM with 32-bit numpy installed it returns a MemoryError.
If I declare my matrices like this:

```
K = 20
N = 8100
D = 600

A = np.random.random((D, N, K))
B = np.random.random((N, K))
```

I don't get any errors. But the problem is that when I declare them in the constructors of the classes I'm using It returns a memoryerror. These are the constructors:

```
class CLASS1:
    def __init__(self, w, h, n, c1, c2):
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.N = n
        self.Z = np.eye(self.N)
        self.Y = np.zeros((self.N, self.N))
        self.L = np.zeros((self.N, self.N))
        self.C1 = c1
        self.C2 = c2
```

The error in this class is from the line in which I'm initializing Y matrix.
And:

```
class CLASS2:
    def __init__(self, BM, W, K, N, D):
        self.betaMask = BM==0
        self.W = W
        self.K = K
        self.N = N
        self.D = D
        self.s = np.random.random((D, N, K))
        self.beta = np.random.random((N, K))
```

here it returns an error on the line I'm defining matrix s in. I use them like this:

```
C1 = 1
C2 = 0
width = 300
height = 200

K = 20
N = 8100
D = 600

L = CLASS1(width, height, N, C1, C2)
A = CLASS2(mask, W, K, N, D)
```

Comment: Numpy is not officially supported on Win64bit archs yet (there are unofficial blobs though). Are you sure you're running a 64-bit version and not a 32-bit one ?

Comment: Matrix `A` uses around `742M` of RAM. This doesn't look like a 32 bit issue. Maybe there just isn't enough RAM free on your machine with 4G?

Comment: I tested your example on Windows7 machine (64-bit) with 4GB RAM like yours, and it worked fine. Python 2.7.5, numpy 1.8.1rc1, both 32 bit version. You may want to have a look at np.memmap (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html)

Comment: Can you show the full class constructor and the exact traceback?

Comment: Question contains answer,,,,,,

Comment: You are still not providing the traceback. What is the exact size of the matrix you want to create? Can you print the values of `self.n`?

Comment: sorry I don't have full access to the windows system. I'm going to add the traceback in a while but self.n is 8100